# looping through an object with javascript

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, json, object

I have a json object with dummy information. I wanna be able to display my data by having a title then a description. When I loop through my information it shows the 3 titles then the 3 description. where I just want title description, title description, title description. What am I doing wrong? below is my json data and my loop

#### Sample data

```
{
  "sample": {
    "insurance": {

      "keyWord": "insurance",
      "definition": "some brief shit talk on what it is that we can do",

      "data": [{
        "link": "http://placehold.it/350x350",
        "title": "this is a title",
        "img": "http://placehold.it/350x350",
        "desc": "Cras ultricies ligula sed magna dictum porta. Proin eget tortor risus. Vivamus suscipit tortor eget felis porttitor volutpat. "
      }, {
        "link": "http://placehold.it/350x350",
        "title": "this is a title3",
        "img": "http://placehold.it/350x350",
        "desc": "Cras ultricies ligula sed magna dictum porta. Proin eget tortor risus. Vivamus suscipit tortor eget felis porttitor volutpat. "
      }, {
        "link": "http://placehold.it/350x350",
        "title": "this is a titl4",
        "img": "http://placehold.it/350x350",
        "desc": "Cras ultricies ligula sed magna dictum porta. Proin eget tortor risus. Vivamus suscipit tortor eget felis porttitor volutpat. "
      }, {
        "link": "http://placehold.it/350x350",
        "title": "this is a title5",
        "img": "http://placehold.it/350x350",
        "desc": "Cras ultricies ligula sed magna dictum porta. Proin eget tortor risus. Vivamus suscipit tortor eget felis porttitor volutpat. "
      }]
    },
    "cover": {
      "keyWord": "cover",
      "definition": "some brief shit talk on what it is that we can do",

      "data": [{
        "link": "http://placehold.it/350x350",
        "title": "this is a title",
        "img": "http://placehold.it/350x350",
        "desc": "Cras ultricies ligula sed magna dictum porta. Proin eget tortor risus. Vivamus suscipit tortor eget felis porttitor volutpat. "
      }, {
        "link": "http://placehold.it/350x350",
        "title": "this is a title2",
        "img": "http://placehold.it/350x350",
        "desc": "Cras ultricies ligula sed magna dictum porta. Proin eget tortor risus. Vivamus suscipit tortor eget felis porttitor volutpat. "
      }]
    },
    "damage": {
      "keyWord": "damage",
      "definition": "some brief shit talk on what it is that we can do",

      "data": [{
        "link": "http://placehold.it/350x350",
        "title": "this is a title",
        "img": "http://placehold.it/350x350",
        "desc": "Cras ultricies ligula sed magna dictum porta. Proin eget tortor risus. Vivamus suscipit tortor eget felis porttitor volutpat. "
      }, {
        "link": "http://placehold.it/350x350",
        "title": "this is a title2",
        "img": "http://placehold.it/350x350",
        "desc": "Cras ultricies ligula sed magna dictum porta. Proin eget tortor risus. Vivamus suscipit tortor eget felis porttitor volutpat. "
      }]
    },
    "water": {
      "keyWord": "water",
      "definition": "some brief shit talk on what it is that we can do",

      "data": [{
        "link": "http://placehold.it/350x350",
        "title": "this is a title",
        "img": "http://placehold.it/350x350",
        "desc": "Cras ultricies ligula sed magna dictum porta. Proin eget tortor risus. Vivamus suscipit tortor eget felis porttitor volutpat. "
      }, {
        "link": "http://placehold.it/350x350",
        "title": "this is a title2",
        "img": "http://placehold.it/350x350",
        "desc": "Cras ultricies ligula sed magna dictum porta. Proin eget tortor risus. Vivamus suscipit tortor eget felis porttitor volutpat. "
      }]
    },
    "theft": {
      "keyWord": "water",
      "definition": "some brief shit talk on what it is that we can do",

      "data": [{
        "link": "http://placehold.it/350x350",
        "title": "this is a title",
        "img": "http://placehold.it/350x350",
        "desc": "Cras ultricies ligula sed magna dictum porta. Proin eget tortor risus. Vivamus suscipit tortor eget felis porttitor volutpat. "
      }, {
        "link": "http://placehold.it/350x350",
        "title": "this is a title2",
        "img": "http://placehold.it/350x350",
        "desc": "Cras ultricies ligula sed magna dictum porta. Proin eget tortor risus. Vivamus suscipit tortor eget felis porttitor volutpat. "
      }]
    }
  }
}
```

#### JS Code

```
var applyAssets = function(asset, a) {
  var assetsLi = document.getElementById('assetsLi')
  var assetsDesc = document.getElementById('assetsDesc')
  var assets__list = document.getElementById('assets__list')

  for (key in asset) {

    if (key === a) {
      var assetKey = asset[key];
      assetsDesc.innerHTML = assetsDesc.innerHTML + '<div class="assets__description--inner"> <span class="phrase">' + assetKey.keyWord + '</span> <span class="definition">Definition:</span> <i>' + assetKey.definition + '</i> <div class="close"> <button type="button" id="closeAsset" name="button">X</button> </div> </div>'

      for (n in assetKey.data) {
        assets__list.innerHTML = assets__list.innerHTML + ' <li><a href="' + assetKey.data[n].link + '"> <div class="grid__full-width"> <img src="' + assetKey.data[n].img + '" alt="' + assetKey.data[n].title + '" /> </div> <h3>' + assetKey.data[n].title + '</h3> <p>' + assetKey.data[n].desc + '</p> </a></li></div>'
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Wheres asset defined??

Comment: so to call the JSON im using this CB which is where the asset is getting defined `ajaxCall(function(data) {
                applyAssets(data, a);
            });`

Answer (score 0):

You can use jQuery.each:

```
$.each(asset, function(i, elem) {
    $.each(elem.data, function(j, item) {
       var title = item.title; 
       var desc = item.desc;
        //build html
    }
}
```

Comment: but I need the keyword and definition then display the data

Comment: so if I send `trigger('cover')` I wanna be able to match that and give back the information thats associated with that value